# Logic: Related to iff condition

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I stuck with following. 
Suppose $A \implies B,C$ and $B \implies A$, can I write $A  \iff B,C$
-Pooja

Comment: Do you mean: $A\Longrightarrow B\wedge C$

Comment: Yes, In post question "," means "and"

Comment: Why not use truth tables?

Comment: That does work, then, because $B, C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Certainly $A\implies (B \wedge C)$ (that's given). You only need to show that if $B\wedge C$ is true, then so is $A$. But if $B\wedge C$ is true, isn't $B$ true? And what does that tell you, considering the as-yet-unused remaining hypothesis?

**Comment:** It is often easiest to tackle proofs of "$\Leftrightarrow$" by proving each direction "$\Rightarrow$" and "$\Leftarrow$" separately.